# Usage of "Will" with 2 verbs?

Tags: modal-verbs

How will it be correct:

> *It will cost $5 and take 2 hours.*

**Or**

> *It will cost $5 and will take 2 hours.*

Comment: Both are correct. Depending on what you want, you may use either option. But firstly, we need to know why you insist on picking one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct but the first is more idiomatic and can be used safely in both conversation and writing. It is assumed that "will" applies to all items in the list. However, if the time taken is uncertain, then you would say "It will cost $5 and **may** take 2 hours."